# Selective jogl texture transparancy depending on bitwise magic?

Tags: java, textures, transparency, jogl

I have rewritten some code to allow to load bitmaps to be loaded as textures and if a pixel has a max green color component it is marked transparent. What is odd is that I cannot use the value from a ByteBuffer that holds transparency without keeping the green intact, I can however replace it with a different color component and the green goes away however then the transparency is altered in an undue way.

```
public static Texture readTexture(String filename, boolean storeAlphaChannel) throws IOException {
  return readPixels(readImage(filename), storeAlphaChannel);
}

private static Texture readPixels(BufferedImage img, boolean storeAlphaChannel) {
    int[] packedPixels = new int[img.getWidth() * img.getHeight()];

    PixelGrabber pixelgrabber = new PixelGrabber(img, 0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), packedPixels, 0, img.getWidth());
    try {
        pixelgrabber.grabPixels();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }

    ByteBuffer unpackedPixels = BufferUtil.newByteBuffer(packedPixels.length * 4);

  for (int row = img.getHeight() - 1; row >= 0; row--) {
    for (int col = 0; col < img.getWidth(); col++) {
      int packedPixel = packedPixels[row * img.getWidth() + col];
      if ((byte) ((packedPixel >> 8) & 0xFF) == 127) {
        unpackedPixels.put((byte) -127);
        unpackedPixels.put((byte) -127);
        unpackedPixels.put((byte) -127);
        unpackedPixels.put((byte) -127);
      } 
      else {
        unpackedPixels.put((byte) ((packedPixel >> 0) & 0xFF));  //rgb...a?
        unpackedPixels.put((byte) ((packedPixel >> 8) & 0xFF));
        unpackedPixels.put((byte) ((packedPixel >> 16) & 0xFF));
        //unpackedPixels.put((byte) ((packedPixel >> 24) & 0xFF)); //this makes green come up
        unpackedPixels.put((byte) -((packedPixel >> 0) & 0xFF)); //this makes it look kinda ok, however not pixel perfect(seems different color), other options of changing this to -packedPixel >> 8 have little/no effect. using (byte) 100 makes green show up as well
      }
    }
  }

  unpackedPixels.flip();

  return new Texture(unpackedPixels, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
}

public static class Texture {
    private ByteBuffer pixels;
    private int width;
    private int height;

    public Texture(ByteBuffer pixels, int width, int height) {
        this.height = height;
        this.pixels = pixels;
        this.width = width;
    }
    //getters
}

//here is where all the magic happens
int loadTextureGL(String src, boolean wrap) {
    pgl = (PGraphicsOpenGL) g;
    GL gl = (GL) pgl.beginGL();
    game.glu = new GLU();

    gl.glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    gl.glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    if (settings.antialiasing) gl.glEnable(GL.GL_SMOOTH);
    gl.glEnable(GL.GL_BLEND);
    gl.glEnable(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    gl.glBlendFunc(GL.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    int mtgl = game.mapTextureGL.length+game.sceneryTextureGL.length;

    Texture mapTextureGL = null;
    try {
        println(sketchPath+"/"+src);
        mapTextureGL = readTexture(sketchPath+"/"+src, false);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        //return -1;
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    int[] tmpT = new int[1];
    tmpT[0] = mtgl;

    gl.glGenTextures(1, tmpT, 0);
    gl.glBindTexture(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mtgl);
    gl.glTexEnvf(GL.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL.GL_MODULATE);

    if (settings.textureMagNearest) {
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL.GL_NEAREST);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL.GL_NEAREST);
    } else {
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL.GL_LINEAR);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL.GL_LINEAR);
    }
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL.GL_REPEAT);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL.GL_REPEAT);

    if (settings.anisotropic && gl.isExtensionAvailable("GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic") ) {
        float max[] = new float[1];
        gl.glGetFloatv(GL.GL_MAX_TEXTURE_MAX_ANISOTROPY_EXT, max, 0);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_MAX_ANISOTROPY_EXT, max[0]);
    }

    try {
        game.glu.gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_RGBA, mapTextureGL.getWidth(), mapTextureGL.getHeight(), GL.GL_RGBA, GL.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, mapTextureGL.getPixels());
        makeRGBTexture(gl, game.glu, mapTextureGL, GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, true);
    } catch(GLException e) {
        System.err.println("Textures failed to bind");
    } catch(BufferUnderflowException e) {
        System.err.println("Textures failed to bind due to underflow");
  }
  pgl.endGL();

  return mtgl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean, "**from** a ByteBuffer that holds transparency"? It looks to me like you are writing **to** a ByteBuffer. Also, what does "this makes green come up" mean?

From my understanding of your code, I can see two problems:

- The minimum value for a `byte` is `-128`, not `-127`. Lines 21 to 24 should therefore use `-128`.
- If a pixel is not transparent, then it I guess it should be opaque. So line 31 should be `unpackedPixels.put((byte) 127);`

Comment: I meant once the bytes have been added to it, it holds the transparency. When I say it is green, the code should be taking pixels that have a value of 127 (max) green and turning them 100% transparent, if they do not have that they should simply be as transparent as is stored in image (as some graphics are in bitmap and some in png).

When I change line 31 to what you say the same error happens, the maxed out green shows completely- this is why I am stumped.

Comment: Maybe the endianness of your input data is not the expected one? Try to replace `0, 8, 16, 24` with `24, 16, 8, 0` in your `>>` operations. By the way, a screenshot (PNG) of your input image and your result would help a lot!

Comment: http://imgur.com/e3LOb to show results of endian-testing and green artifact. Please note in first image, I could have done the first three bytes the same as the bottom one, and had gotten the image colors correct- however the trasparancy channel would not have worked and would only be on/off per pixel and that is not what I want since some have gradient transparency. When done 24, 16, 8, 0 the image is very red. It's like something is wrong with the 24 push that makes it behave oddly but I don't see what it could be? I'm guessing it has something to do with how I'm loading the image?

Comment: Thanks. Your second screenshot says 16-8-0-24 and gives correct colours but green patches, but your code above says 0-8-16-24 gave correct colours and green patches. Which is which? Did they give similar results? By the way, you shouldn't use `-x` to get the inverse of a colour, but `-1-x`, because the range for bytes is `-128..127`.